# Suppressing ARP Entry for WIX Burn Bundle

Tags: wix, wix3.7

I am creating a WIX Bootstrapper using WIX Burn. The resultant bundle "exe" will be consumed by another application or rather a MetaInstaller. Now the application executes the bundle as a process with arguments but we don't want to make any entry in ARP for the bundle.

Is there any way to achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. In the [Bundle](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/bundle.html) element, set these attributes

```
<Bundle DisableRemove="yes" DisableModify="yes"
```

> **DisableRemove**
>
> If the "**DisableModify**" attribute is also "yes" or "button" then the bundle will not be  displayed in Progams and Features

You should note, however, WiX burn is a package manager. So you should ensure that your uninstallation process invokes it to clean up the bundle and unused non-Permanent packages.