# WiX and ARPINSTALLLOCATION

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.7

I want my MSI package to write the value `InstallLocation` into `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\\(Wow6432Node)\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\\(GUID)`. You should also see this value in the Add/Remove Programs Control Panel (column `Location`).

To set this value via WiX, I read that the property *ARPINSTALLLOCATION* should be set by a custom action. I reduced the `<Product>` to a minimum. This is how it looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
     xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension">
  <Product Id="*" 
           Name="MyApplication"
           Language="1033" 
           Version="!(bind.FileVersion.MyApplication.exe)" 
           Manufacturer="Me"
           UpgradeCode="db37f5dc-68c5-46ee-bbdf-704ff68b70db">
    <Package InstallerVersion="400" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" Languages="0" />
    <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />

    <!-- use SetProperty as suggested by Rolo -->
    <SetProperty Id="ARPINSTALLLOCATION" Value="[INSTALLDIR]" After="CostFinalize" />
    <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="MyApplication" Level="1">
      <ComponentGroupRef Id="MyApplication.Files.AllRequired" />
    </Feature>
  </Product>
  <Fragment>
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
        <Directory Id="INSTALLDIR" Name="MyApplication" />
      </Directory>
    </Directory>
  </Fragment>
  <Fragment>
    <ComponentGroup Id="MyApplication.Files.AllRequired">
      <Component Id="ProductComponent" 
                 Guid="90EA8F1C-77D2-40E1-81AD-44B076EFAB9D" 
                 Directory="INSTALLDIR">
        <File Id="MyApplication.exe" Source="$(var.MyApplication.TargetDir)\MyApplication.exe" />
      </Component>
    </ComponentGroup>
  </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

The MSI is bundled within a WiX Standard Bootstrapper.

Comment: Obvious comment maybe, but it won't be there if it's a per user install (see HKCU) or if it's a 64-bit install.

Comment: In the package there is _InstallScope="perMachine"_ so it should be either in HKLM\Software\... (or in the Wow6432Node). In any case it should show up in the Add/Remove Programs Control Panel in the column _Location_

Comment: I updated the code above to have a complete (but reduced) `<Product>`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should execute your custom action in both sequences (InstallExecuteSequence and InstallUISequence) and sequence it after CostFinalize.

You can simplify this using something like this:

```
<SetProperty Id="ARPINSTALLLOCATION" Value="[INSTALLDIR]" After="CostFinalize" />
```

Comment: @Johannes could you please provide the relevant part of the installer log?

Comment: Action start 09:15:07: CostFinalize.
MSI (s) (0C:6C) [09:15:07:660]: Doing action: SetARPINSTALLLOCATION
MSI (s) (0C:6C) [09:15:07:660]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: ActionText
Action ended 09:15:07: CostFinalize. Return value 1.
MSI (s) (0C:6C) [09:15:07:662]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding ARPINSTALLLOCATION property. Its value is 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MyApp\'.
Action start 09:15:07: SetARPINSTALLLOCATION.
MSI (s) (0C:6C) [09:15:07:663]: Doing action: MigrateFeatureStates
MSI (s) (0C:6C) [09:15:07:663]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: ActionText 
Action ended 09:15:07: SetARPINSTALLLOCATION. Return value 1.`

Comment: For some reason, the new-line character is not working in the comment, shall I add it to the question?

Comment: @Johannes Your log looks right, I also tested your code locally and it worked. Now the question I have is... Where are you looking for this value? I can see it in the registry and "Programs and Features" (ARP). When you are in "Programs and Features" change your view to "Details",  right click the header of the columns i.e. Name and click "More", then look for the "Location" column and add it. You will see the value there, otherwise you won't see it in the summary at the bottom of the window.

Comment: I didn't mention that I have a bootstrapper which is installing the MSI. Never thought that this makes a difference. When I install the software using the MSI everything works fine. But when using the  WiX bootstrapper (which includes the MSI), it does not create the registry keys.

Comment: @Johannes in that case you need to add the "Visible=yes" attribute to your MsiPackage element.

Comment: Okay that makes sense. But then there are 2 entries in Add/Remove Programs. I would like to have only 1 entry (the bootstrapper). Is it somehow possible that the bootstrapper is writing the InstallLocation?

Comment: @Johannes I think your original problem is resolved right? Regarding this new question, what you can do is avoid the bootstrapper to create the entries in ARP, you will find additional information in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22626992/suppressing-arp-entry-for-wix-burn-bundle